# is to possible to assign all zero's to all bits for 128 bits?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int* p= (int*)malloc(8);

    for(i=0;i<128;i++)
    p=0;

}
```

i want to assign all zero's for all 128 bits. Is the above code is correct? i want clarification. my aim is to allocate 128 bits to one varaible and assigning all zero's to all 128 bits.

Comment: Your pretty much confused here. I think you need to start with a basic book on C and pointers

Comment: The smallest addressable unit of storage in C is one *byte*, which is the content of a `char`-type variable. A sufficient number (i.e. `128 / CHAR_BIT`) of bytes, all set to zero, should do the trick.

Comment: There are 4 bugs here: wrong value of malloc arg, wrong type for p, wrong loop count, wrong assignment to p ... plus an undesirable cast of malloc and bad indentation. You need to pay attention to the difference between bits, bytes, and ints, and to pay attention to your arithmetic. Programming takes discipline, and this code displays none.

Answer (score 5):

No. You simply assign 0 to the pointer itself (so you lose it and leak memory). Use this:

(Edit: as Jim Balter pointed out, it's easy to handle non-8 bit chars:)

```
int main()
{
    unsigned n = (128 + CHAR_BIT - 1) / CHAR_BIT;
    unsigned char *p = malloc(n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    p[i] = 0;
}
```

But this is reinventing the wheel. Why not use the standard function `memset()`?

```
int main()
{
    unsigned n = (128 + CHAR_BIT - 1) / CHAR_BIT;
    unsigned char *p = malloc(n);

    memset(p, 0, n);
}
```

Comment: Why memset if you can calloc?

Comment: @KerrekSB because maybe you don't want to write out the multiplication when it's unneeded. Or maybe you want to initialize the array contents to another value later. Nevertheless, this solution is good, yours is also, please don't start trolling me again.

Comment: ... +1, small buffer overflow error - you allocate `8` bytes, but you memset `8*sizeof(int)` bytes.

Comment: This clears 8 * sizeof(int) bits, which is an unknown number, whereas the OP wants to clear 128.

Comment: @JimBalter hope that this is good now. As per the standard, char is always one byte (I know, I know, there are non 8-bit bytes, but this is uncommon enough to safely ignore...)

Comment: @H2CO3 the standard says that `sizeof(char)` is one it doesn't say that this is a byte.

Comment: @Motti That is incorrect; the standard does say that a char is a byte.

Comment: For posterity, the answer ought mention that a char isn't necessarily 8 bits. It's easy enough to replace 16 with `(128+CHAR_BIT-1)/CHAR_BIT`

Comment: Er, well, you changed it in the malloc but not in the loop or memset ... which illustrates the danger of violating the number one principle of good software design: not replicating information.

Comment: Or you could just use 16 * `uint8_t` instead of char.  Or 8 *  `uint16_t` or 4 times `uint32_t` or 2 * `uint64_t`

Comment: @JeremyP If chars aren't 8 bits then uint8_t won't be defined. You can use int_least8_t, but that may be less efficient than the CHAR_BIT calculation.

Comment: @JimBalter `uint8_t` wasn't the only alternative I suggested.

Comment: @JeremyP None of those alternatives are required to be defined either.

Comment: @JimBalter they are mandatory if the implementation provides actual types of the corresponding width with no padding and 2's complement.  Have you ever programmed with a C compiler that didn't have at least one of those?

Comment: @JeremyP "mandatory if" = "optional". The Standard says "optional". We are talking here about what can be *assured*, not what you or I or anyone else has encountered. And there are machines with 36-bit words and none of those types, whether or not C implementations exist for them. End of discussion for me.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, there's just so much to pick apart on that...

1) you allocate 8 bytes, which is 64 bits

2) you iterate to 128, which would cause a buffer overflow, except that:

3) in your loop you only ever set the first byte allocated to 0

there are two ways to do this:

```
p = malloc(128/8);
for (i = 0; i < (128/8); i++)
    p[i] = 0;
```

or you can just use the memset(3) function, provided in all POSIX operating systems.

Comment: The OP's loop doesn't set *any* of the allocated bytes. Also, 8 isn't necessarily the number of bits in a byte; you should use CHAR_BIT.

Comment: To be even more picky - there are no *guarantees* in the language that all bits of an `int` is part of the value. So there *could* be one or more non-zero bits left, even if the value is set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of allocating and clearing it, `calloc()` would be better I think.

```
int* p= (int*)malloc(8);
```

You allocated 8 bytes i.e 8*8 = 64 bits only.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{

int i = 0;
char *p = calloc(16, sizeof(char));

//for Testing
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  printf("%d\t", *p++);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `memset` routine to nullify as many bytes as you nned. It will look like this:

```
uint8_t* p= (uint8_t*)malloc(16);
memset(p, 0, 16);
```

Please note, if you want 128 bits (which is 16 bytes) you need to replace 8 to 16.

**Updated:**

Since sizes of integer types are system dependent, using `uint8_t` typedef makes you confident the type you are working with is really 8 bits long. This typedef (as well as the ones for other integer types of fixed size) can be found in `stdint.h`. If using this header is not possible, you can create these typedefs yourself e.g. `typedef unsigned char   uint8_t` is true for most of the systems.

If the code is later ported to a system with different integer sizes, you don't have to worry about the problems with size incompatibility - all you need is simply changing `(u)intX_t` (u - for unsigned, X - number of bits) typedefs.

Comment: Note that we cannot know that 64 or 128 bits is an exact number of ints. int is simply the wrong type to use here.

Comment: Correct, I think the most portable solution would be to use a typedefs for basic integer types where the particular number of bits is guaranteed (uint8_t) taken either from stdint.h or from a header file of my own where all the platform specific typedefs are.

Comment: Yes, but your answer should reflect that.

Comment: Note that uint8_t need not be defined, and won't be one a machine without 8-bit bytes.

Answer (score 1):

int sometimes allocates 4 bytes depending on the platform. so use char instead:

```
char* p= (char*)malloc(16);
for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    p[i]=0;
```

Comment: Note that a char is not necessarily 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

The above code will assign 0 to the pointer, not the content.

To initialize the content, use memset:

```
memset(p, 0x00, 8);
```

or dereference the pointer:

```
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    p[i]=0;
```

Comment: What's the type of `p`? If it's `int*` as in the OP's example, then the number of bits cleared is unknown, and if it's `char*`, that only clears 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Use `calloc( )` to allocate and zero.